# Can we disable the bluetooth notification on android device when connected?

Tags: bluetooth

Whenever I connect my headphone, my android device starts to show the bluetooth device is connecting even though I paired at earlier time.

Is there a way to disable this notification from asking each time when a bluetooth device is connected. Please tell me whether there is an option available in developer mode.

My device: Samsung Galaxy M14-5G
Android version: 13
One UI Core version: 5.1

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what notification that asks each time you mean. Usually if I enable a previously connected BT device it is automatically connected or if I had it connected to a different device in between I have to manually select it in the list of previously connected devices in BT settings.

Comment: @robert when I turn on bluetooth, I get a notification showing the headset is connecting and after some seconds I can see status as connected and then I need to press the done button to remove the notification screen from my phone. I don't want this notification, let my bluetooth device connected automatically without a confirmation message. As for a first time connection this pop up window is nice because we can select what device we need to connect. Is there a way to disable this pop up window.

Comment: This could be a manufacturer modification as I have never seen this on a plain Google Android device. Please edit your question and add details about your phone model and Android version.